# Visualize the selected Item in xamarinForms UWP datagrid

Tags: xamarin.forms, datagrid, visualization, selection, selecteditem

I am doing my first project with xamarin forms. Could someone please tell me how i can visualize in a texbox a selected item .
so when i select an item in my table(datagrid) i should visualize in a textbox (type entry) the selected item.
Thanks
[Click here to visualize the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6DIJ.png)

Comment: Xamarin does not have a DataGrid control.  There are multiple third party controls, and we have no way of knowing which one you are using.

Comment: Sorry! i meant i have created my table using datagrid dependency installed

Comment: Could you provide the code for us and with more details about what you want?

Comment: Hi, i just add an image to my request. so i'd like to visualize the name, the modbus and the size value when i select an item in the table. how this can be done in mvvm please?

Comment: What is the DataGrid you used? Could you provide the code you tried?